# PHPUnit in Laravel doesn't run when adding folders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I wanted to break my testing into their M, V, C folders. So I have:

```
/tests
    /models
    /views
    /controllers
    TestCase.php
```

As an example, I have a `UsersControllerTest.php` inside `/controllers`:

```
class UsersControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function testSimple()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

When I run `phpunit`, all I get is `Configuration read from PATH_TO_phpunit.xml`. The problem arises when I add a test file inside a folder. If I move that test file to the root `/tests` folder, then everything works fine.

I tried to edit the `phpunit.xml` file to include:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./app/tests</directory>
        <directory>./app/tests/controllers</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

But it still didn't work

Comment: Read that phpunit.xml file, there are paths PHPUnit considers while running tests, your seems to be outside that path.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. So what I am suppose to do? How can I add my other paths?

Comment: Analogically to that already existing. If you have <filter> with one path, add another along.

Comment: So I tried adding more `<director>`, but still same problem.

Comment: Maybe better read PHPUnit's documentation on topic. You don't need to add a subdirectory if directory is already added. I think you have problem with autoloader - check if that testing class is loaded at all. Laravel's autoloader is pretty simple compared to other, better suited frameworks, maybe it's searching only in main directory.

Comment: It seems like it is loaded. If i change the test inside the controller to say `hideTestSimple`, then when I run phpunit, it says `No tests found in class "UsersControllerTest"`. So it is loading the class

Comment: NVM, found the problem. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Good to hear that, I'd like to read it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution was much simpler that I anticipated. All you have to do is add an asterix, `*`, to the end of the directory path inside `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./app/tests/*</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: This is interesting, my current projects runs recursively into subfolders without having asterisks.

Comment: @Unnawut, what version of PHPUnit are you using? I'm using the latest 4.1. Maybe this is a bug with this version?

Comment: Ah right. I'm using 4.3-dev (set to dev-master in composer.json). That's probably the reason.